# How do i copy all the pictures on a website?

Tags: website, mirroring

I want to copy all the pictures on a site, but I don't know how to do it.
Could you please tell me? Shall I use a tool?

Comment: What have you found so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: I removed the URL from the title because this question applies to any website, not just that specific one.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know your operating system.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Firefox, you can install the [DownThemAll addon](http://www.downthemall.net/) to download all the images displayed on a given webpage.

Comment: Dag nab it... I was inches away from the submit button when your answer showed up lol - But yes. This addon is what I would recommend as well.

Answer (score 5):

the command

```
wget --mirror -A jpg,gif,png,bmp,jpeg http://www.the-url.org/
```

will download jpgs, gifs, pngs, and bmps from a site.

if you are cursed to use windows http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can use this on the command-line:

```
wget --mirror
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/).

It copies everything on a site, including pictures, images, Flash, video, `.php` and `.html`.

Comment: it downloads "php"? hard to believe.