# Can't copy website with curl

Tags: macos, curl

I want to get all the images from a website behind our company firewall, similar to what was asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/200552/how-do-i-copy-all-the-pictures-on-a-website).  I can access the site from Firefox on OS-X, but when I try to use curl I get:

> ## You are not authorized to view this page
>
> You do not have
>   permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that
>   you supplied because your Web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate
>   header field that the Web server is not configured to accept.
>
> ---
>
> Please try the following:
>
> - Contact the Web site
>     administrator if you believe you should be able to view this directory
>     or page.
> - Click the Refresh button to try again
>     with different credentials.
>
> ### HTTP Error 401.2 -
>   Unauthorized: Access is denied due to server
>   configuration.
> Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> ---
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> - Go to Microsoft Product
>     Support Services and perform a title search for the words
>     **HTTP** and **401**.
> - Open **IIS Help**, which is
>     accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr),  and search for topics titled
>     **About Security**, **Authentication**, and **About Custom
>     Error Messages**.

Shouldn't this be able to work given that Firefox can do it?  Firefox asks me for my user name and password, so I've tried giving that on the command line, e.g.:

```
curl http://site -o index.html --create-dirs -u me:mypass
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Besides what was mentioned about auth mechanisms below, you can try logging into the site in Firefox, using an add-on to export all your cookies to a text file, then use `curl --cookie <cookie file>` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using the [DownThemAll addon](http://www.downthemall.net/) for firefox that was suggested in the question you linked to.

Curl is probably using a [different authentication method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) than what the server wants. Look in the manual for curl for more authentication methods. You can try accessing the page in curl without credentials to get a hint on what it wants.

You should also try using `https://` in curl in case that is something the server requires.